# StackOverflow in Eclipse Juno SR 2 during initialization

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-overflow

My Eclipse Juno SR 2 installation was not able to start and returned an error dialog during initialization.
My environment:

- Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit (a know a bit old)
- Java 1.6.0_27
- Eclipse Juno Service Release 2
- Build id: 20130225-0426

Having a look into the workspace log (.metadata/.log) gave me this hints:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-11-21 17:47:07.728
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (75).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.isDelta(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:445)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.assembleWith(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:139)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.assembleWith(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:96)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode.assembleWith(AbstractDataTreeNode.java:147)
...
```

So it seems Eclipse hang up with an Stackoverflow during initialization...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found a workaround:
Removing all contents at the folder: **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects**
lead to an working eclipse installation without any projects inside.
So I did not have to reinstall and could keep my settings/preferences.
Only thing to do was to reimport all my projects from the local disk.

Comment: maybe starting eclipse with -clean could have been also a useful thing but I did not remember it. mh - I made a copy of the workspace maybe I can try it again.

Comment: -clean did not work. Got the same problem after a while again maybe I have too much projects inside my workspace. This time I also had to remove the **.snap** file in the ...resources folder (it grew up to ~20MB).